# write csv file to server with codeigniter csv_from_result

Tags: codeigniter, csv

Trying to save a csv file on my server with codeigniter.

my syntax is:

```
   $this->load->dbutil();
   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id,customeraccount,band FROM Customer_Bands");
   $delimiter = ',';
   $newline = "<br>";
   echo $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query, $delimiter, $newline); 


if ( ! write_file(base_url().'/application/authorizations/test.csv', $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query, $delimiter, $newline)))
       {
            echo 'Unable to write the file';
       }
       else
       {
            echo 'File written!';
       }
```

This is rough right now but want to get functionality working first.

Two issues.
Firstly the `echo $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query, $delimiter, $newline);` outputs to my view correctly but each field is inside "", how can I remove these?

Secondly, the file is not writing to my server.
base_url() is my codeigniter root folder then inside applications I have created a folder named authorizations so `base_url()/application/authorizations`

This currently fails and echos `'Unable to write the file'`

Thanks in advance

Comment: what i can see is you are saving the file  to `application/assets` and not to `application/authorizations`

Comment: Sorry bipen, typo. has been corrected but issues the same. Thanks.